# Static method with a nested class

Tags: java, nested

The following code does not compile due to the line marked XX. If the **dress()** method is changed to be non-static, then this does compile.

Can someone please explain whether this is just because the **dress()** method doesn't have access to non-static classes or whether it's more complicated than that?

```
public class Wardrobe {
    abstract class Sweater {
        int insulate() {return 5;}
    }
    private static void dress() {
        class Jacket extends Sweater {    // XX
            int insulate() {return 10;}
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Comment: Note: whenever you ask a question that says "this doesn't compile" it's really important to copy/paste the exact compilation error, too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the question now to remove the TShirt class and add the error message

Comment: The error suggests that the problem is that you have an inner class `Sweater` that requires an instance of `Wardrobe`.

Comment: Strange, IntelliJ doesn't show this error at compilation time, only at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner class `Sweater` is not static inside `Wardrobe`. That means that it requires an instance of `Wardrobe`.

Inside the static method `dress`, there is no instance of `Wardrobe` under consideration, so trying to refer the inner class `Sweater` causes a compile error.

An easy fix is to make `Sweater` a static nested class:

```
public class Wardrobe {
    static abstract class Sweater {
        int insulate() {return 5;}
    }
    ...
}
```